# I can't open Atom Text Editor from my command line on windows 10 64bit

Tags: atom-editor

i got problem here, I could not use Atom via CLI mode to run command like

```
atom .
atom filename.php
```

but i still can use `apm` as well. What wrong with my Atom installation?, The error can be seen on the picture below.

`atom` command not work
[image: atom command not work]

`apm` works as well!
[image]

Comment: My crystal ball says that `apm` is in your path, whereas `atom` is not. A basic system administration question, unrelated to programming.

Comment: is already on my PATH here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/a/VwWUE